# In TICKscript (Kapacitor), how will you split the string?

Tags: kapacitor, chronograf

For example,
var str1 = "abc.test.com:8080"

I need something as follows,

var splitted = split(str1,":")

var only_hostname = splitted[0] //will give abc.test.com*

How can we actually achieve the same in TICKscript?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variable as a regex...Something like var str1 =~ /abc.test.com/ so you will aggregate by host independant of ports...

I never need exactly your use case, but maybe in the go specs you could find what you need!

Comment: I need to extract the specific string only from the given variable. We can use regex to check or validate whether specific string or there or not. I found "strTrimRight(s, cutset string) string" option. But after I used like "var splitted = strTrimRight("abc.test.com:8080", "8080" string" I could not use splitted as variable. It is failing as "invalid TICKscript: unsupported literal type tick.unboundFunc".